# cin strings into a Vector (c++)

Tags: c++, vector, cin

So I am basically trying to the same thing 2 different ways.
The while loop is perfect but it stores the "." in the vector which I do not want to do but its the only way to exit the loop.

The second with the copy function; I don't know how to break or exit.
I believe this would help others.

Could I have some pointers in my investigation?
Thank you

```
while (keyinput != ".")
{
    cin >> keyinput;
    words.push_back(keyinput);
}

copy(std::istream_iterator<string>(cin),
    std::istream_iterator<string>(),
    back_inserter(words));
```

Comment: I am using visual studio 2015 which I think might mean something with regards to debugging the copy function. thx

Comment: Could people who downvote please explain why so we don't get downvoted again and know what is acceptable. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-downvotes

Comment: Please ignore the copy iterator; I got it fixed and will post once I test for correctness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `do...while` loop:

```
do {
    if (!(cin >> keyinput)) {
        // error handling...
        break;
    }
    if (keyinput == ".") break;
    words.push_back(keyinput);
}
while (true);
```

Comment: Of course, this can be simplified by using  `cin >> keyinput` directly as the condition for the `while` loop.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice: sure, if you don't need to handle input errors (unless you delay that validation until after the loop exits), in which case you could also put the check for `"."` in the loop condition as well: `while ((cin >> keyinput) && (keyinput != ".")) words.push_back(keyinput);`

Comment: OIC, the `if` statement does make a convenient place to print an error message or other error handling. Of course, in the former case, `continue` might be more appropriate than `break` (assuming `cin` is reset as well).

Comment: @Code-Apprentice: Only if the input error is a recoverable error, such as bad input that is discarded and the user is prompted to keep typing.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to re-order things so the check is done before the push_back

```
cin >> keyinput;
while (keyinput != ".")
{
    words.push_back(keyinput);
    cin >> keyinput;
}
```

Comment: So this does help me learn but now the first element of my vector is null. I see comment below which suggest a do while loop which I will implement and test. thx

Answer (score 2):

Let's analyze your code a line at a time:

Check for a `"."` in the input

```
while (keyinput != ".") {
```

Get next input

```
    cin >> keyinput;
```

Add input the the vector

```
    words.push_back(keyinput);
}
```

Note that when the user finally enters a `"."`, it will be added to the vector.

In general, any code which affects the condition of a while loop should be immediately before the while loop checks the condition without any lines of code in between. There are two ways to accomplish this:

1. Get input immediately before the while loop and at the end of the while loop.
2. Use a `do`..`while` loop instead.

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't want to store `.` into vector. You have to insert the `value` just before you are taking input inside `while` loop.

```
std::cin >> keyinput;
while(keyinput != ".") {
    words.push_back(keyinput);
    std::cin >> keyinput;
}
```